# How to run external executable using Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, executable

I have an external executable file which I am trying to run from a Python script. CMD executable runs but without generating output. Probably it exit before output can be generated. Any suggestion about how to delay exit until outputs are generated?

```
import subprocess, sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
exe_str = r"C:/Windows/System32/cmd C:/temp/calc.exe"

parent = subprocess.Popen(exe_str, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Maybe you are right. Input data is elevation and flow direction that is why i posted it here.

Comment: DOS? Do you not mean a command line interface (CLI) appliction? [MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) was discontinued over 12 years ago.

Comment: yes I mean command prompt. thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: It worked from SO example using os:

`import sys, string, os`
`os.chdir( 'c:\\temp' )`
`os.system( '"C:\\temp\\calc.exe"' )`

Not sure why subprocess isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run an exe file with the arguments using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928956/how-to-run-an-exe-file-with-the-arguments-using-python)

Answer (score 22):

use `subprocess.call`, more info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\calc.exe"])
```

or

```
import os
os.system('"C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"')
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: It runs but without generating output. I tested executable using cmd and it requires at least 2-3 sec before generating output. This is the issue, how to make it stay for 3 sec before exit using python?

Comment: Weird. Even with 3 sec condition it didn't generate any output. I increased time but no use. Not sure what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 14):

The `os.system` method is depreciated and should not be used in new applications. The subprocess module is the pythonic way to do what you require.

Here is an example of some code I wrote a few weeks ago using `subprocess` to load files, the command you need to use to delay exit until data has been received and the launched program completes is `wait()`:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "c:\\file.exe"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)
process.wait()
```

On Windows platforms, `creationflags=0x08000000` is an optional parameter that suppresses the launch of a window,  which can be useful if the program you are calling does not need to be directly seen.

Comment: It is still not generating outputs. Runs perfectly from cmd window but no output using pythonic way as you suggested.

Comment: Note, when running on Linux: `ValueError: creationflags is only supported on Windows platforms`

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe')
```

**Option 2**

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()
```

**Option 3**

```
import os
os.system('C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe')
```

Comment: Thanks. Might be useful to present the difference between these calls.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after trying everything else:
Change the location of your python program to be the same as where the `.exe` is located.
And then the simple:

```
subprocess.call("calc.exe")
```

would work.