# how to run an exe file with the arguments using python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess

Suppose I have a file `RegressionSystem.exe`. I want to execute this executable with a `-config` argument. The commandline should be like:

```
RegressionSystem.exe -config filename
```

I have tried like:

```
regression_exe_path = os.path.join(get_path_for_regression,'Debug','RegressionSystem.exe')
config = os.path.join(get_path_for_regression,'config.ini')
subprocess.Popen(args=[regression_exe_path,'-config', config])
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work how? What's the error message?

Answer (score 30):

You can also use [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) if you want.  For example,

```
import subprocess
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')    #use this if you want to suppress output to stdout from the subprocess
filename = "my_file.dat"
args = "RegressionSystem.exe -config " + filename
subprocess.call(args, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=False)
```

The difference between `call` and `Popen` is basically that `call` is blocking while `Popen` is not, with `Popen` providing more general functionality.  Usually `call` is fine for most purposes, it is essentially a convenient form of `Popen`.  You can read more at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681715/whats-the-difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-call-how-do-you-use-them-to).

Comment: Python 3 [docs: subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Answer (score 24):

For anyone else finding this you can now use `subprocess.run()`. Here is an example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["RegressionSystem.exe", "-config filename"])
```

The arguments can also be sent as a string instead, but you'll need to set `shell=True`. The official documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: And again, the documentation is crap. Do we really need to pass `"-config filename"` or is it `"-config", "filename"`? Calling the executable an argument does not really make sense either.

Answer (score 3):

```
os.system("/path/to/exe/RegressionSystem.exe -config "+str(config)+" filename")
```

Should work.

Comment: os.system appears to block. That is, not return until the exe has run to completion. That is a noteworthy feature/constraint of this propose solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here i wanna offer a good example. In the following, I got the argument `count` of current program then append them in an array as `argProgram = []`. Finally i called `subprocess.call(argProgram)` to pass them wholly and directly :

```
import subprocess
import sys

argProgram = []

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Get arguments from input
    argCount = len(sys.argv)
    
    # Parse arguments
    for i in range(1, argCount):
        argProgram.append(sys.argv[i])

    # Finally run the prepared command
    subprocess.call(argProgram)
```

In this `code` i supposed to run an executable application named `Bit7z.exe" :

> ```
> python Bit7zt.py Bit7zt.exe -e 1.zip -o extract_folder
> ```

***Notice :*** *I used of `for i in range(1, argCount):` statement because i dont need the first argument.*

Answer (score 0):

I had not understood how arguments work.
Ex: "-fps 30" are not one but two arguments which had to be passed like this (Py3)

```
args=[exe,"-fps","30"].
```

Maybe this helps someone.