# Run an exe file with parameters to browse a file

Tags: python

I want to use dull razor software, where in it asks for a source file in it.
(Shown in the picture below).

Also another dummy image link needs to be provided.

[image]

The execution of the exe file needs to be done using python code. How to pass parameters so that I can run this software?

Any tips or help will be appreciated.

Thank you:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run an exe file with the arguments using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928956/how-to-run-an-exe-file-with-the-arguments-using-python)

Comment: In case your question is specifically about passing command-line arguments to **that** program, it's off-topic.

Comment: @Celeo Thanks for the link provided. I had found that earlier, but I couldn't understand it. Can I specify the file path in my argument?

Comment: Certainly. Take a look at the second answer - it includes the full path to the executable file.

Comment: hava a look at [Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python)

Comment: @stefan thanks a lot, I will have a look at it!

Comment: @Celeo , what needs to be supplied in place of str(config). Can you throw some light on config command?

Comment: `config` in that question is just part of the arguments to that executable. All you need is `subprocess.call('C:/path/to/file.exe -argument1 -argument2')` etc.

Comment: @Celeo thanks for the last comment! The program actually opened. But according to my question, how can I provide two source files and automatically click  start button? I cant use the software browse button because the code will run behind the scenes.

Comment: That's dependent on that software itself if it provides such a command-line option. If it doesn't, you have the option of using a program like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to click the button.

Comment: @stefan any idea how to insert text when there are two text boxes. It is a conflict situation! As provided in the picture in the question, there are two editboxes.

Comment: never tried it by myself. you did hav a look at the pywinauto [FAQ](http://pywinauto.pbworks.com/w/page/9546214/FAQ)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot for how to automate a software.

I found sendkeys very useful.

It took a lot of time to install sendkeys on python 2.7 and also its website was shut. So it was a nice experience to install it with the help of Mingw

Here is what I write in my python code:

```
import win32com.client
import subprocess
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate("DullRazor for Windows")
shell.SendKeys("{TAB}", 0)
```

And so on to automate the software according to my needs.

Thank you @Celeo and @stefan