# launch an exe with parameter from python

Tags: python, exe, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to call an application and pass a text file as a parameter. The text file has instructions.  I tried passing a parameter when opening notepad but couldn't get it to work.  Here is the code I'm trying:

```
import os

os.startfile(r"C:\Windows\notepad.exe c:\cobra\advancecalendar.txt")

If I don't include the path to the second file it launches notepad, but with the file name included i get the following error:

RESTART: C:/Users/timbo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Open exe module.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/timbo/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Open exe module.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.startfile(r"C:\Windows\notepad.exe c:\cobra\advancecalendar.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe c:\\cobra\\advancecalendar.txt'
```

How can I pass a parameter to the startfile so it opens a specific file?  when I tried putting both in quotes it still got an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928956/how-to-run-an-exe-file-with-the-arguments-using-python

Comment: Try searching a bit more, I think this gets asked pretty often.

Comment: Use `os.startfile()` just with the file, without the application.

Comment: Thanks. I didn’t see one with parameters but was probably to narrow in my search will dig in again

Answer (score 2):

Use the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r"C:\Windows\notepad.exe", "c:\cobra\advancecalendar.txt"])
```

Tested in **python2.7**

Comment: Thanks’ that should solve another problem I was having too.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks